# Can I do concurrent cobyla optimizations using Accord.Net?

Tags: c#, optimization, concurrency, accord.net

The code below is a minimal working example of a circle estimator i'm using. It usses Accord.Net's cobyla optimizer. The input for the localize method is a set of points. The center location is found using the optimizer and returned. (My real code is a bit more complicated but I left out most less relevant stuff)

The code is working fine but the issue I have is with the `static` fields (I have more of them in my real code). When I optimize multiple problems concurrently the `static` field will give problems because the optimizer might read values intended for another thread.

The question is how do I make this code work for concurrent code? Can I ditch the statics and still get the points inside the `Func<double[], double>`? Are there other ways to circumvent the concurrency problems with the statics?

```cs
    internal class CircleLocalizer
    {
        private static (double, double)[] points; // I dislike these statics!
        private double[] prior = { 0, 0 };

        Func<double[], double> objective = x =>
        {
            var distancesToCenter = CircleLocalizer.points.Select(p => Distance.Euclidean(new[] { p.Item1, p.Item2 }, new[] { x[0], x[1] }));
            var averageDistance = distancesToCenter.Average();
            return distancesToCenter.Select(d => Math.Pow(d - averageDistance, 2)).Sum();
        };

        public double[] Localize((double, double) points)
        {
            CircleLocalizer.points = points;

            Cobyla cobyla = new Cobyla(2, objective);
            cobyla.Minimize(Prior);

            return cobyla.Solution;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is not using statics an option?

Comment: I would love to, but I don't know how to pass the ```points``` variable to the ```objective``` function because it must be a ```Func<double[], double>``` for the cobyla optimizer. And if I add them to the ```double[]``` parameter cobyla will start to optimize them which is not correct

Comment: Cobyla is a derivative-free method. You may get better performance using different algorithms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest rewriting `objective` to a regular method that takes the points as a parameter:

```
double Objective(double[] x, (double, double)[] points){
     var distancesToCenter = points.Select(p => Distance.Euclidean(new[] { p.Item1, p.Item2 }, new[] { x[0], x[1] }));
     var averageDistance = distancesToCenter.Average();
     return distancesToCenter.Select(d => Math.Pow(d - averageDistance, 2)).Sum();
}
```

and call it like

```
new Cobyla(2, x => Objective(x, points));
```

When you are writing a [lambda function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions) you can 'capture' variables in the outer scope. Internally this is converted to an object with all the captured variables as fields in the class.

Comment: Cobyla doesn't accept the points parameter like this. But! This does allow me to make the ```this.points``` non-static! Which solves my problem. I call it now with ```new Cobyla(2, x => Objective(x));```
Thanks a lot. I'll accept your answer and invite you to slightly alter it by leaving out the points in the objective and use this.points instead. Big thanks for your help!

Comment: @Goosebumps I'm not sure what you mean. The signature of Cobyla is `Cobyla(Int32, Func<Double[], Double>)`. Using a lambda to capture `points` should be fine, assuming points is a `(double, double)[]`. In your example it is a `(double, double)`, but I assume that is a typo. But if you prefer to keep it as a field that should also work fine.

Comment: My bad. It does work! Not sure what went wrong the first time, Must have been some other error...